# Triggering the PRODUCT entity

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Looking at `data/en_core_web_lg/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0/ner/moves`, their is a `PRODUCT` entity. According to the [doc](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#named-entities), `PRODUCT` represents

> Objects, vehicles, foods, etc. (Not services.)

However, if I try the sentence `'machine guns, pineapples, motorbikes, biscuits, donuts, knives'`, no entity is generated. Does anyone know how to trigger the `PRODUCT` entity?

Thanks